# Displaying username using $_SESSION['username']

Tags: php, session-variables, login-script

When I try to display the username of a logged-in user I get 'Welcome, 1' where 1 should be the username of the person logged in.
This is my code in the members.php. The commented out line doesn't work either.

```
<?php
require_once('include.php');
?>
<?php
// echo "welcome, {$_SESSION['username']}";     
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

echo "Welcome $user";

?>
```

The user is logged in, I wonder if I've made a mistake in the check-login page.
The code for the check_login page is:

```
<?php 
require_once('include.php');

$username = trim($_POST['user']);
$password = trim($_POST['pass']);

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' and password='$password';";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count !== 0){

$_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
header("location:members.php?user=$username");
exit; 
}
else {
$_SESSION['logged-in'] = false;
header("location:login_again.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

which redirects to the members.php page upon successful login.
Anybody have any ideas why the username is '1' everytime?
Many thanks

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `$_SESSION['username']`?

Comment: You are passing the username in `$username = trim($_POST['user']);` not with the superglobal `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there needs to be a `session_start()` somewhere at the top of your code

```
<?php session_start();
require_once('include.php');
?>
<?php
// echo "welcome, {$_SESSION['username']}";     
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

echo "Welcome $user";

?>
```

you also need to set it before accessing it with `session_start` at the top of this file also

```
if($count>0){
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
$_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
header("location:members.php?user=$username");
exit; 
}
```

your code is open for sql injection attacks, Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead

Comment: Thanks. Can you include the session_start() function in the include.php?

Comment: Thankyou, something simple then.

Answer (score 0):

In your check_login page I don't see either **session_start** and the **code for saving username into session** so that you can retrieve it on the other page.

In check_login page please add:

```
session_start();
```

at the start and then set:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

so that you can retrieve and display it on the other page.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following points.

- Make sure you set username in the Session variable.

From your code, I do not see any line like following:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username
```

Without setting, you can get nothing.

- If you did `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION` variable.

`session_start()` is required function to be called if you gonna use $_SESSION variable.